# Если хеш-функция для строк исключает возможность коллизии, то набор хеш-кодов {1101, 115, 1103} может быть сгенерирован для строкового массива

Tags: java, функции, хеширование

Если хеш-функция для строк исключает возможность коллизии, то набор хеш-кодов `{1101, 115, 1103}` может быть сгенерирован для строкового массива...

1. `{"four", "three", "two", "one"}`
2. `{"one", "two", "two"}`
3. `{"three", "two"}`
4. `{"one", "two", "three"}`

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: 4, так как три числа (1 и 3 отпадают), а из-за исключения возможности коллизии мы также не можем использовать второй вариант (two повторяется)